# Horizontal scrolling UL with buttons and "width:auto" lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, horizontal-scrolling

As the title suggests, I am trying to create a horizontal scrollable `<ul>` with `<li>` with `width:auto` and with prev and next buttons, clearly with `overflow:hidden`.
Any suggestions on how to manage it with jquery?
This is the code that I have prepared...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a39wxo69/4/)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <span class="arrow">&lt;</span>
  <span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>Abbaiare</li>
    <li>Bolle</li>
    <li>Cantante</li>
    <li>Domodossola</li>
    <li>Elefante</li>
    <li>Giovanni</li>
    <li>Hotel</li>
    <li>Inti</li>
    <li>Montagna</li>
    <li>Nave</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
  width:calc(100% - 120px);
  height:60px;
  background-color:#dbdbdb;
  padding:0 60px;
  margin-top:60px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:99; 
}
.arrow {
  display:block;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:101;
}
.arrow:first-of-type {
  left:0;
}
.arrow:nth-of-type(2) {
  right:0; 
}
#nav {
  width:auto;
  height:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  white-space:nowrap;
  transition:2.0s;
}
#nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px;
  font-size:13px;
  padding:0 30px;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `bxSlider`? Why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: How can I use `bxSlider` with only text and not full width list item?

Comment: See my answer... Refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`bxSlider`](https://bxslider.com) without reinventing the wheel. To make your code work, you just need to add:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#nav').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideWidth: 150,
    slideMargin: 25
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}
.bx-viewport {
  height: 50px !important;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>Abbaiare</li>
    <li>Bolle</li>
    <li>Cantante</li>
    <li>Domodossola</li>
    <li>Elefante</li>
    <li>Giovanni</li>
    <li>Hotel</li>
    <li>Inti</li>
    <li>Montagna</li>
    <li>Nave</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer,
But I need to have a full width `<ul>` with not fixed width `<li>`
Like the JSFiddle link I've posted above

Comment: @Sieen If you want a full width, which was the first one, remove the `width` from the CSS. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok but the point is that the `<ul>` must show all possible lists in 100% of its width and not just one...

Comment: @Sieen Okay, I got it.

Comment: Definitely! But there's a problem with the scrolling, it skip some list and the <ul> it's not full width... Thanks for your patience
Look the update: https://jsfiddle.net/a39wxo69/10/

Comment: Thanks again, but unfortunately this is not what I needed

Comment: Okay... There are loads of options in bxSlider. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it will be useful for anyone, This what I needed...
(Thank you Praveen Kumar)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a39wxo69/12/)

```
$(".arrow:first-of-type").click(function() {
        var navwidth = $("#nav");
        navwidth.animate( { scrollLeft: '-=200' }, 1000);
    }
);
$(".arrow:nth-of-type(2)").click(function() {
        var navwidth = $("#nav");
        navwidth.animate( { scrollLeft: '+=200' }, 1000);
    }
);
```